# Error Confirmar Reenvio de Formulario

Tags: php, html, login

Al hacer login con un usuario en mi web, envio los datos mediante **POST** a un php que me comprueba el usuario en una BBDD y crea unas variables de sesión:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['logado'] = true;
$_SESSION['id_empresa'] = $fila['id'];
$_SESSION['nombre'] = $fila['nombre'];
$_SESSION['email'] = $fila['email'];
$_SESSION['telefono1'] = $fila['telefono1'];
$_SESSION['telefono2'] = $fila['telefono2'];
```

Una vez logado, si navego a otra pagina de mi web, comprueba si la  variable `$_SESSION['logado']` está en true, si no lo está, me redirige al index.php.

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["logado"]) || $_SESSION["logado"] != true)
header('Location: index.php');
```

Hasta aquí todo correcto. El problema viene cuando dentro de las páginas de la web, le doy al boton hacia atrás. Al darle me aparece el error **Confirmar reenvío del formulario** y tengo que recargar la pagina para que funcione.

En otra web que tengo, lo realizo de la misma manera y puedo navegar con los botones de hacia atrás y hacia adelante por todas las paginas de mi web sin ningún tipo de problema.

`Ajax`

```
oAjax.open("POST","login.php",true); 
var datos = "idempresa="+idempresa+"&contrasenia="+contrasenia+"&nocache="+Math.random(); 
oAjax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
oAjax.send(datos)
```

`HTML FORM`

```
<form class="" action="empresas.php" method="post" name="login_empresa">
 <h1><strong>EMPRESA</strong></h1> 
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="empresa"> <h1>
<strong>CONTRASEÑA</strong></h1> <input type="password" class="form-control" name="contrasenia"> 
<button type="button" onclick="valida_login_empresa(document.login_empresa.empresa.value,document.login_empresa.contrasenia.value)">ENTRAR</button> </form>
```

¿Alguien sabría decirme que haría falta para que funcionara en condiciones?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Muestra como estás enviando el formulario del login

Comment: Usando AJAX. `oAjax.open("POST","login.php",true);
  var datos = "idempresa="+idempresa+"&contrasenia="+contrasenia+"&nocache="+Math.random();
  oAjax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  oAjax.send(datos);` y el archivo login php los recibe mediante POST:

Comment: Y al momento de ingresarlo?

Comment: Añade el formulario que hiciste a la pregunta

Comment: `<form class="" action="empresas.php" method="post" name="login_empresa">
          <h1><strong>EMPRESA</strong></h1>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="empresa">
          <h1><strong>CONTRASEÑA</strong></h1>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" name="contrasenia">
            <button type="button" onclick="valida_login_empresa(document.login_empresa.empresa.value,document.login_empresa.contrasenia.value)">ENTRAR</button>
</form>`

Comment: Y después de que ajax te devuelve una respuesta, cómo lo mandas a la pagina?

Comment: Devuelve una S si ha encontrado a la empresa en la BBDD `if (oAjax.responseText == 'S')
      {
        document.login_empresa.submit();
      }` y hace el submit del formulario. No entiendo porque es necesario saber tanto de como hace el login si eso si lo hace correctamente :/

Comment: Ese es el error, cuando le das el `submit()` el envia el formulario que tienes hecho a la pagina con todos los datos, entonces, sí recargas la pagina el va a confirmar que los datos que enviaste por `submit()`  son los mismo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya que lo estás enviando con el `submit()`, él envia todo los datos que tiene el formulario, por eso cuando intentas recargar la pagina, el tiene aún los datos por post que se enviaron con el `submit()` por lo tanto el confirma sí son los mismos.

Una solución podría ser que, en vez de enviarlo a la pagina por `submit()` lo hagas por medio de `JavaScript` con un `window.location.replace("url")` que lo que hace es redirigirte a la pagina y además borra el registro de la pagina en la que estabas o simplemente con un `window.location.href("url")`, espero y te funcione, Saludos

Comment: El problema no me lo da al recargar la página, ahí se que es normal que confirme los datos introducidos. El poblema me lo da cuando dentro de una pagina de la web le doy hacia atras para que muestre la pagina en la que se estaba anteriormente. En el otro proyecto donde si me funciona, tambien lo realice a traves de submit y no me ocasionó ningun problema

Comment: Por eso mismo, estás intentando volver a la pagina que envia esos datos por post

Comment: Estoy intentando volver a la página principal del usuario una vez logado, no a la pantalla del login. en la pagina principal del usuario empresa.php ni recibe ni manda ningun dato por POST. Lo unico que hace es que al principio del fichero comprueba si existe la variable $_SESSION['logado'] = true; y si no existe, te manda a la pagina del login de nuevo. y si la sesion esta iniciada, muestra los datos de ese usuario

Comment: Intenta el método que te acabo de mandar, es que como tal cuando tu estás volviendo a atrás, el va a recuperar los datos que le enviaste en el momento que accediste, pero sí lo haces directamente desde la url, ves que no va a pasar nada, porque no le has enviado ningún formulario

Comment: Intentalo de esta manera y me cuentas

Comment: Genial, con eso ya no me da el error. Thx DaxTter77 ;)

Comment: Me alegra mucho, recuerda que puedes marcar la respuesta como correcta y votarla positivamente, saludos!!